# Why there is no output from HTML <select> to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make selection with different prices for each `selectedIndex`.

But whenever I press count that does not work. What should I change?

Where is the problem? Am I choosing the wrong option for the function?

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <div class="range1">
    <label for="range" class="label">Your points</label>
    <input id="a" type="range" name="range" min="1300" max="2100" step="10" value="1400">
    <output for="range" class="output"></output>
    </div>
    <div class="range2">
    <label for="range" class="label">Desired Rank</label>
    <input id="b" type="range" name="range1" min="1300" max="2100" step="10" value="1700">
    <output for="range1" class="output2"></output><br>
<label for="range" class="label">Select your class: </label><br>
<select id="classes" name="Class" class="label" style="width:300px;">
  <option selectedIndex="1">Blade Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="2">Kung Fu Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="3">Destroyer</option>
  <option selectedIndex="4">Force Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="5">Assassin</option>
  <option selectedIndex="6">Summoner</option>
  <option selectedIndex="7">Blade Dancer</option>
<option value="class4" disabled="disabled">Warlock</option>
<option value="class4" disabled="disabled">Soul Fighter</option>
</select>
    </div>
<br><br>
  </form>
<label for="range" class="label">Price: </label>
<h2><p id="Answer">0€</p></h2>
<p id="test"></p>
<button class="label" type="button" onclick="onClick()">Count</button>
<b><h4>* Zen Beans are included in price!</h4></b>
</center>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

   

        <script>
    $("[name=range]").on("change", function() {
    $("[for=range]").val(this.value +" " );
    }).trigger("change");

    $("[name=range1]").on("change", function() {
    $("[for=range1]").val(this.value +" " );
    }).trigger("change");
 
 
 function onClick() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
 var b = document.getElementById("b");
 var classes = document.getElementById("classes");
 var aSelectedValue = a.value;
 var bSelectedValue = b.value;
 var SelectedClass = classes.selectedIndex;

    
    if (SelectedClass == "1" && SelectedClass == "4") {
    
    if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug1";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.1875 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.625 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.1875 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.1875 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.625 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.625 + 56.25 + "€";
    
   }
  
 } else if (SelectedClass == "2" && SelectedClass == "5") {
  
    if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug2";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.165 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.55 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.165 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.165 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.55 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.55 + 49.5 + "€";
    
   }
  
  
 } else if (SelectedClass == "3" && SelectedClass == "6" && SelectedClass == "7") {

 if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug3";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.15 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + 45 + "€";
    
   }
 
 
} }
</script>
```

Comment: Comparing whether a string is greater than another string rarely hits correct result.

Comment: how this condition is going to be `true` : `SelectedClass == "1" && SelectedClass == "4"` ?

Comment: My bad.... I haven't noticed that ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions like `SelectedClass == "1" && SelectedClass == "4"` never become true. I think you meant to use `||` instead. Also note that `selectedClass` starts from `0`. Also note that `classes.selectedIndex` doesn't return option's `selectedIndex` attribute. So I changed comparison strings to integer and decreased by one. Here is the overall changes:

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <div class="range1">
    <label for="range" class="label">Your points</label>
    <input id="a" type="range" name="range" min="1300" max="2100" step="10" value="1400">
    <output for="range" class="output"></output>
    </div>
    <div class="range2">
    <label for="range" class="label">Desired Rank</label>
    <input id="b" type="range" name="range1" min="1300" max="2100" step="10" value="1700">
    <output for="range1" class="output2"></output><br>
<label for="range" class="label">Select your class: </label><br>
<select id="classes" name="Class" class="label" style="width:300px;">
  <option selectedIndex="1">Blade Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="2">Kung Fu Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="3">Destroyer</option>
  <option selectedIndex="4">Force Master</option>
  <option selectedIndex="5">Assassin</option>
  <option selectedIndex="6">Summoner</option>
  <option selectedIndex="7">Blade Dancer</option>
<option value="class4" disabled="disabled">Warlock</option>
<option value="class4" disabled="disabled">Soul Fighter</option>
</select>
    </div>
<br><br>
  </form>
<label for="range" class="label">Price: </label>
<h2><p id="Answer">0€</p></h2>
<p id="test"></p>
<button class="label" type="button" onclick="onClick()">Count</button>
<b><h4>* Zen Beans are included in price!</h4></b>
</center>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

   

        <script>
    $("[name=range]").on("change", function() {
    $("[for=range]").val(this.value +" " );
    }).trigger("change");

    $("[name=range1]").on("change", function() {
    $("[for=range1]").val(this.value +" " );
    }).trigger("change");
 
 
 function onClick() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
 var b = document.getElementById("b");
 var classes = document.getElementById("classes");
 var aSelectedValue = a.value;
 var bSelectedValue = b.value;
 var SelectedClass = classes.selectedIndex;

    
    if (SelectedClass == 0 || SelectedClass == 3) {
    
    if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug1";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.1875 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.625 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.1875 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.1875 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.625 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.09375 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.625 + 56.25 + "€";
    
   }
  
 } else if (SelectedClass == 1 || SelectedClass == 4) {
  
    if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug2";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.165 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.55 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.165 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.165 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.55 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.0825 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.55 + 49.5 + "€";
    
   }
  
  
 } else if (SelectedClass == 2 || SelectedClass == 5 || SelectedClass == 6) {

 if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug3";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.15 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + 45 + "€";
    
   }
 
 
} }
</script>
```